# Why is my function to decode from base64 not working?

Tags: c++, vector, encoding, base64, decode

I have this code:

```
static char Base64Digits[] =
 "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

std::string ToBase64Simple( const unsigned char* pSrc, int nLenSrc)
{
   std::string pDst;
   int nLenOut= 0;
   int count = 0;
   while ( nLenSrc > 0 ) {
      unsigned char s1= pSrc[0]; 
      unsigned char s2= 0; if (nLenSrc>1) s2=pSrc[1]; 
      unsigned char s3= 0; if (nLenSrc>2) s3=pSrc[2];

      unsigned int n;
      n =  s1;    
      n <<= 8;   
      n |= s2;   
      n <<= 8;   
      n |= s3;  

      unsigned char m4= n & 0x3f;  n >>= 6;
      unsigned char m3= n & 0x3f;  n >>= 6;
      unsigned char m2= n & 0x3f;  n >>= 6;
      unsigned char m1= n & 0x3f;  

      unsigned char b1 = Base64Digits[m1];
      unsigned char b2 = Base64Digits[m2];
      unsigned char b3 = Base64Digits[m3];
      unsigned char b4 = Base64Digits[m4];

      pDst.push_back(b1);
      pDst.push_back(b2);
      if ( nLenSrc >= 3 ) { 
         pDst.push_back(b3);
         pDst.push_back(b4);
      }
      if ( nLenSrc == 2 ) {
         pDst.push_back(b3);
         pDst.push_back('=');
      }
      if ( nLenSrc == 1 ) { 
         pDst.push_back('=');
         pDst.push_back('=');
      }
      pSrc    += 3;
      nLenSrc -= 3;
      nLenOut += 4;
   }
   return pDst;
}

static unsigned char LookupDigits[] = {
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //gap: ctrl chars
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //gap: ctrl chars
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,           //gap: spc,!"#$%'()*
62,                   // +
 0, 0, 0,             // gap ,-.
63,                   // /
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, // 0-9
 0, 0, 0,             // gap: :;<
99,                   //  = (end padding)
 0, 0, 0,             // gap: >?@
 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25, // A-Z
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,    // gap: [\]^_`
26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,
43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51, // a-z    
 0, 0, 0, 0,          // gap: {|}~ (and the rest...)
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
};

int FromBase64Simple( std::string pSrc, std::vector<unsigned char> vec)
{
   for( int j=0; j<pSrc.size(); j+=4 ) {
      unsigned char s1= LookupDigits[pSrc.at(j)];
      unsigned char s2= LookupDigits[pSrc.at(j+1)];
      unsigned char s3= LookupDigits[pSrc.at(j+2)];
      unsigned char s4= LookupDigits[pSrc.at(j+3)];

      unsigned char d1= ((s1 & 0x3f) << 2) | ((s2 & 0x30) >> 4);
      unsigned char d2= ((s2 & 0x0f) << 4) | ((s3 & 0x3c) >> 2);
      unsigned char d3= ((s3 & 0x03) << 6) | ((s4 & 0x3f) >> 0);

      vec.push_back(d1);  
      if (s3==99) break;     
      vec.push_back(d2);  
      if (s4==99) break;  
      vec.push_back(d3);  
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I found it online and modified it to use std::strings and unsigned char vectors instead of pointers.

Encoding works perfectly: I've been checking it with an online encoder and decoder. Decoding returns an empty vector each time. Why is this?

I call it using this code:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> byteVec;
byteVec.push_back('a');
std::string str = ToBase64Simple(&byteVec[0], byteVec.size());
std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
std::vector<unsigned char> vec;
FromBase64Simple(str, vec);
std::cout<<vec.size()<<std::endl;
```

a correctly translates to YQ==, but not back.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in `vec` by reference:

```
int FromBase64Simple( std::string pSrc, std::vector<unsigned char> &vec)
```

Otherwise you're working with a local copy and nothing gets back to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Result vecror is passed to the decode function by copy and so it is modified in the function but not the actual parameter in the caller site.
Pass it as reference to vector: `std::vector<unsigned char>&`